# C# syntax error, nothing seems wrong

Tags: c#, syntax-error

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace SchoolPasswordLockFolder
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Enter the password: "); // the space character after the semicolon has an error
            public string input = Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

The errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1513  } expected  SchoolPasswordLockFolder    c:\Users\CENSOREDSIJGIOFSGJIOFS\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\SchoolPasswordLockFolder\SchoolPasswordLockFolder\Program.cs 14
```

(for the one after the semicolon)
and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   SchoolPasswordLockFolder    c:\Users\CENSOREDIDONTWANTSTALKERS\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\SchoolPasswordLockFolder\SchoolPasswordLockFolder\Program.cs  19
```

(for the last bracket)
I have not programmed in C# for a very long time as I was too busy with web development and lua...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this:

```
public string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

to:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

local variables do not get accessibility modifiers like `public`.